# WMI ManagementScope connect failure with RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_INTEGRITY error on remote machine

Tags: c#, wmi, dcom

I am getting the following error in the event viewer on the remote machine

> The server-side authentication level policy does not allow the user Machinename\user SID (X-X-X-XX-XXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXX) from address XX.X.XX.XXX to activate DCOM server. Please raise the activation authentication level at least to RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_INTEGRITY in client application.

when trying to run the following code

```
var Connection = new ConnectionOptions();
Connection.Username = "MyUsername";
Connection.Password = "MyPassword";
var Scope = new ManagementScope(string.Format(@"\\{0}\root\cimv2", Address), Connection);
Scope.Connect();
```

It works fine when running the exact same code from another machine, so I suspect it is some configuration on the client machine that is not correct but I cannot find what it might be. The above call throws "Access Denied" exception.

Comment: I'ver experienced it working on some clients that have older sub-releases that didn't get the DCOM hardening patch linked below. 

The November update may resolve the issue, but you can also use the Registry key bypass until March of 2023.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5004442-manage-changes-for-windows-dcom-server-security-feature-bypass-cve-2021-26414-f1400b52-c141-43d2-941e-37ed901c769c

Comment: Also, 
Try adding 
Connection.AuthenticationLevel.PacketIntegrity;

Comment: @JeffS it seems that just adding Connection.AuthenticationLevel.PacketIntegrity is not working if the client doesn't have the patch, which seems weird to me. Do you known any other workaround for non patched clients?